# Eureka service instance is stopped in docker but in eureka server it always says its up

Tags: java, microservices, netflix-eureka

Got an issue with eureka health check. eureka.client.healthcheck.enabled: true. With that even if I stop my service manually, eureka server says its up. Can some give me some advice on how to get service status DOWN?

Comment: Just to clarify, you added this `eureka.client.healthcheck.enabled: true` to the client right?

Answer (score 1):

So client services send heartbeats to the server, to indicate their status.

The default value is 30 seconds which means that the client will send one heartbeat every 30 seconds.

You can configure that: `eureka.instance.lease-renewal-interval-in-seconds=30`

You can find more details [here](https://www.baeldung.com/eureka-self-preservation-renewal) and here is a [Github thread](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/1780)

There is also something called Self-preservation `eureka.server.enable-self-preservation`

It is a feature where Eureka servers stop expiring the client instances from the registry when they do not receive heartbeats (from peers and client microservices) beyond a certain threshold.

### So you have those main configurations:

- `eureka.server.enable-self-preservation`: Configuration for disabling self-preservation – the default value is true
- `eureka.server.expected-client-renewal-interval-seconds`: The server expects client heartbeats at an interval configured with this property – the default value is 30
- `eureka.instance.lease-expiration-duration-in-seconds`: Indicates the time in seconds that the Eureka server waits since it received the last heartbeat from a client before it can remove that client from its registry – the default value is 90
- `eureka.server.eviction-interval-timer-in-ms`: This property tells the Eureka server to run a job at this frequency to evict the expired clients – the default value is 60 seconds
- `eureka.server.renewal-percent-threshold`: Based on this property, the server calculates the expected heartbeats per minute from all the registered clients – the default value is 0.85
- `eureka.server.renewal-threshold-update-interval-ms`: This property tells the Eureka server to run a job at this frequency to calculate the expected heartbeats from all the registered clients at this minute – the default value is 15 minutes

Here is a guide for [Eureka Self Preservation and Renewal](https://www.baeldung.com/eureka-self-preservation-renewal)